# Calendar Module Styling of upcoming events

Tags: theming, datetime

I'm trying to remove the left margin/padding on the event items that show in Upcoming Events when you use the Calendar module(see attached pic). Could anyone advise what element it is that I need to change the CSS on, to remove the left margin or padding? I want the items under the heading to appear flush (left aligning) with the heading. I am also using Omega 3 so I'm not sure if thats relevant.
[image]

Comment: this is my website: http://www.abercynonprimary.org.uk

Comment: i changed the view option from HTML List to Unformatted List and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

In the View of the Upcoming Events, i changed the view option from HTML List to Unformatted List and the problem went away. See attached pic.[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: just added a bit more info and a pic above. thanks